# To show that $\dot{x} = -y - x +y^2 - x^2,\; \dot{y} = xy$ has no periodic orbits.

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

I've tried using index theory, but there's a non-isolated fixed point at $(0, 0)$ (the remaining fixed points at $(0, 1)$ and $(-1, 0)$ are saddles).

The terms in the equations have even indices and the wrong signs, so using a Liapunov function $V(x, y) = x^n + a y^m$ won't work.

I've tried using the Dulac function $g = 1/xy$ to get that $\nabla \dot (gF) = \frac{1 - y}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y} < 0$ for $y > 1$, which isn't a strong enough result.

Comment: Would changing to polar coordinates i.e $r \dot{r} = x \dot{x} + y \dot{y}$ work? Or would showing that $\dot{r} = 0$ has no solution just so that a *limit* cycle doesn't exist?

Comment: Why do you say the fixed point $(0,0)$ is not isolated?

Comment: The Jacobian ends up being (-1 -1) in the first row and $(0, 0)$ in the second row. That means the determinant is zero (and the trace is non-zero. I think if both the trace and determinant are zero, and you have a star, then you can assign an index to the fixed point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phase portrait shows there can be no periodic orbits.  Each trajectory must either approach a fixed point or go off to infinity.  For a detailed proof of this, you could examine the fate of solutions starting out in each of the regions into which the isoclines divide the plane.

[image]

Comment: Actually, that picture leads to an analytic proof! With the exception of $(0, 0)$, all fixed points are saddles. Suppose a closed orbit exists. Then any closed curve would have to surround $(0, 0)$ and one other fixed point (since a curve surrounding $(0, 0)$ yields no information that can rule out a closed trajectory). But the $x$-axis has trajectories parallel to it ($\dot{y} = 0$ when $y = 0$), so such an orbit would intersect an $x$-axis trajectory - a contradiction. Hence no closed orbits exist.